# How to hidden query-string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, path

I wanna pass to a resource in a request for example

```
# Go to payment link
<%= link_to 'Payment', checkout_path(pricing: amount.id) %>
```

When I go to payment link the url path is the next:

```
  http://localhost:3000/checkout?pricing=amount_2aHUHuhdn23jnSJd
```

I'd like to hidden the query-string "pricing=amount_2aHUHuhdn23jnSJd" without have to used any gem

UPDATE QUESTION 31/12

This request is of type Get since I need to show the different prices to the user, that's why the parameter pass (pricing: amount.id)

```
<%= link_to 'Payment', checkout_path(pricing: amount.id) %>

get 'checkout', to: 'subscriptions#checkout'
```

I'd appreciate your time and your grain of sand

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for here. Are you saying you do not want the "pricing=amount_2aHUHuhdn23jnSJd" shown in the URL?

Comment: The part after `?` is a so-called [query string](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), not a directory.

Comment: Exactly @ingenierosmnky I wish to hidden query string "pricing=amount_2aHUHuhdn23jnSJd"

Comment: They are parameters (query-string) that I would like to pass so that the user has the possibility to choose different prices in my app

I wish they did not show or at least disguise "pricing=amount_2aHUHuhdn23jnSJd" in the URL @engineersmnky

Comment: Why do you want to hide or obfuscate the value of `amount.id`? Is the value sensitive, or do you need to make sure that the user is not able to change it? Why can't you use the `id` in clear text?

Comment: It is a sensitive value that I would like to hide, the amount.id reflects a hash that I want to disguise (the query string)

"?pricing = amount_2aHUHuhdn23jnSJd"

This is what I want to disguise the user

Comment: Why do you want to disguise it? Why is it a problem if a user knew that the value was for example "amount_2aHUHuhdn23jnSJd"? What exactly is the problem with that hash? Is it a security issue, why?

Comment: More security is aesthetic, my client wants the query strings not to be seen every time the user chooses a price that is hidden as amount.id.

Comment: @SamuelDaCosta the easiest (probably best) solution to that would be a POST request. You can still make it look like a link or a button and it would avoid storage in session which is physical storage and presence in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it in the [Session](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/).

Store it when the user enters the page, clear it when user clicks a link.

```rb
# SomeController#before_payment
session[:pricing] = amount.id

#then..

# CheckoutController#index
pricing = session[:pricing]
session[:pricing] = nil
```

Be careful because it will only live within the session. It will be stored as a cookie, and have a 4kb limit for data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

When the value is sensitive then hiding the value doesn't really fix the problem. Instead, I would suggest encrypting the value in the URL or to use another non-sensitive value instead.

1. Value encryption

You could use Rails [`MessageEncryptor`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.0/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html) to encrypt the value before passing it to the URL and decrypt it later in the controller again.

```
# in app/models/url_encrypter.rb
module URLEncrypter
  ENCRYPTER = ActiveRecord::MessageEncryptor.new(
    Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base.first(32)
  )

  def encrypt(value)
    ENCRYPTOR.encrypt_and_sign(value, purpose: :url)
  end

  def decrypt(value)
    ENCRYPTOR.decrypt_and_verify(value, purpose: :url)
  end
end

# when building the URL
<%= link_to 'Payment', checkout_path(pricing: URLEncrypter.encyrpt(amount.id)) %>

# when reading the param in the controller
pricing = URLEncrypter.decyrpt(params[:pricing])
amount = Amount.find(pricing)
```

2. Have a second non-sensitive, unique identifier

Here you add a second unique identifier to your database table, for example, a column named `uuid` which you could populate automatically in a `before_save` callback with `self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid`

You can then use its value instead of the `id` like this:

```
# when building the URL
<%= link_to 'Payment', checkout_path(pricing: amount.uuid) %>

# when reading the param in the controller
amount = Amount.find_by(uuid: params[:pricing])
```

Comment: While I agree with this answer. I am unsure of what "sensitive" means in the context of the OP. If sensitive means cannot be displayed or should not exist in browser,  then even encrypting it or obfuscating it with a UUID is of little purpose because anyone capturing that information can access the same via the URL (as if they had the "sensitive" value). If sensitive somehow means scoped to the user then signing the encryption with a secret key stored specific to the user might make more sense.  I think right now the question is completely unclear as to the reasoning behind this request.

Comment: Excuse me but I tested your code and it has several errors (the encryption key tells you that the minimum must be 32 bytes)

Thanks anyway for your time and answers.

Comment: I updated my answer to address that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean without seeing your routes.rb file. As mentioned by @Deepak Kumar to hide query from your url you should use POST request. Have a look at [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). You can add below

```rb
post 'payment', to: 'checkout#payment'
```

In your routes.rb. This will call `Payment` action from your `CheckoutsController`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify in the question

It is a get request because I need to show the different prices to the users, that's why I pass the parameters that I need in the request 

<%= link_to 'Payment', checkout_path(pricing: amount.id) %>

get 'checkout', to: 'subscriptions#checkout'

(pricing: amount.id)

Comment: I believe that you can just store this id in session and verifying it each time checkout_path is called. Have a look [at this article](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) it explains session storage really well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and especially for the documentation, it is the closest thing I was looking for, however, I will not be able to give you a reward since the solution as you wrote in the comment :(. Sorry for not knowing how to explain me from the beginning and thank you from beforehand